# jboss hibernate tool configuration, configuration, session factory show normally but database keep pending without error message

Tags: jboss-tools

I create a hiberate tool configuration and when refresh the configuration, Configuraton can show the mapping class, but in Database, it keeps show Pending without any error. The progress bar in the lower right hand side show Fetching children of Database...

what should I do now?

below is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<session-factory>
    <!--  
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">passw0rd</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">dsli01</property>        
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/dsli"/>
    -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">passwd01</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xx.xx.xxx:25100:dsli01.xxx.com</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">dsli01</property>        
        <!--  <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:jboss/datasources/sli01"/>-->
        <!--  <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:jboss/datasources/sli01</property>-->
        
        
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.default_schema">DSLI01</property> -->
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.session_factory.statement_inspector">
            hk.xxxx.slis.dao.SqlCommentStatementInspector
        </property>
.....
```

The hibernate tool launch configuration properties
[image]

[image]